# Why the file from S3 bucket disappeared?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've uploaded a new file (logo.png) in the S3 bucket the problem is after approximately two days the file disappeared. Why this happened?

There are no life cycle rules configured for the bucket.

Comment: Have you had a look at your CloudTrail logs? That should tell you what api call from what user deleted it.

Comment: Amazon S3 does not randomly delete files. It would have been the result of a specific request or a Lifecycle policy.